# Seatpost won't let me set my saddle "level"

Tags: saddle, seatpost

I recently changed my saddle and I've found I'm unable to get my new saddle level (as measured with spirit level).

The problem is the seatpost clamp - it has teeth on both the concave top of the shaft and the convex clamp part that fit together to prevent the saddle angle from changing. These teeth are quite large and they restrict the possible angles the saddle can be set at.

My previous saddle just happened to have an inherent angle that matched the seatpost, so I was able to set it "level" with the ground. I find with my new saddle, it is either slightly tipped forward or slightly tipped back. Neither are satisfactory - I need something in between.

Does anyone have a suggestion for fixing this (short of buying a new seatpost)?

Comment: Place washers between the teeth.

Comment: Why is this a problem? Forget the spirit level. You should set the seat angle to whatever feels comfortable. For me, that means having the front slightly lower than the back; since everyone's ass is shaped differently, the optimal position might be different for other people.

Comment: The problem is that the teeth on the seatpost are too coarse to allow the desired adjustment.

Comment: Place thick plastic pactches (cut from sports drinks bottle) between the lower clamp and the saddle rail.

Comment: I think it might be considered an answer, because it takes in consideration the actual problem behind the question, and suggests a course of action.

Comment: @DanielRHicks are the washers supposed to get the "bite" from the teeth and hold position from them, or just work as a spacer and hold position from pure friction?

Comment: @heltonbiker - thank you. I'm glad someone gets it. What I'm doing here is challenging the implicit assumption behind the question: that the seat always needs to be perfectly horizontal.

Comment: While you are correct that there is no requirement that a seat be level, most saddles are designed to be ridden in that position. In addition, the OP is trying to match the position previously used with a different saddle. So simply saying it isn't a problem doesn't answer the question asked. It does try to go around the problem a different way, but that isn't really relevant here. At least as I read the question. The OP may feel differently.

Comment: Its a fair point but I did say in my Q: "it is either slightly tipped forward or slightly tipped back. **Neither are satisfactory**". I've ridden it with both settings and have left it tilted forward as its the least awful of the two but I'm find I'm continually slipping down the saddle and having to re-adjust. All my other bikes have their saddles level so this the position I'm most comfortable with.

Comment: Ideally you'd get a washer that was soft enough for the teeth to bite into it (and also soft enough to conform to the curve of the joint) while being hard enough that the teeth wouldn't "telegraph" through and leave you with the original problem.  And stainless, of course, or thick brass.

Comment: The washer idea is worth trying - I fear plastic will eventually conform to the teeth pattern (teeth are very pronounced).

Answer (score 6):

Unfortunately, this is a common issue with more basic seat posts.

There are 2 options:

1. Use sandpaper or a Dremel to remove the teeth which fix the angles of the seat post. If you make it completely smooth, then you can use grip tape like that designed for a skateboard deck to add friction without locking you in to specific angles. This approach has drawbacks. The grip tape may need to be replaced on occasion. You need to be careful not to remove too much material from the post, as it risks breaking the post in use. As you can imagine, that would be painful.
2. Replace the seat post with something without that limitation.

I hope that helps.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. The seatpost is carbon (Q2) so replacing it is going to be costly but probably worth it in the long term.

Comment: What frame are you riding?

Comment: full carbon frame - can see bike and seatpost here: http://www.khsbicycles.com/05_flite_850_11.htm

Comment: As expected, the seat post is very basic. It shouldn't be too costly to replace with a proper seat post.